# live changing as typing in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtgui, qlineedit

I have a QlineEdit and a QTableView in a simple program.

I load a table (for example person) from SQLite to tableView.

I want an event or anything else that as I type in lineEdit the tableView change based on it.

For example if the the table person have a field name that filled by:

1. mehran
2. mehsa
3. mahid
4. naser
5. omid

I want when I press "m" all the name that started with "m", like mehran, mehsa, mahid show on the tableView. And when I press next key for example "e", just mehran and mehsa show on tableView, and so on.

Comment: Connect `QLineEdit::textChanged()` signal to a slot, and in the slot query the data base with the entered string. Use database result and update your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do a connection like this based [on this signal](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop):

```
connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [=](const QString &string) {
    QSqlQuery query(QString("SELECT %1 FROM ..").arg(string));
    while (query.next()) {
        QStringList stringList = query.value(0).toStringList();
        updateTableView(stringList);
    }
});
```

At this point in time, you will also need to add the following line in your qmake project file to get the new signal-slot syntax:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Comment: tnx for your response, but my problem has been solved by @vahancho comment.

Comment: @dare: sure, but it is better to have an explained answer for the posterity. ;)

Comment: I agree with you @Laszlo